# Made a mistake on check need help to fix

Tags: check

I wrote a check and put the amount in the pay to order spot. Can I just mark it out, put the name in the spot and finish writing the check?

Answer (score 39):

You really shouldn’t be crossing anything out on a check. Banks will generally not accept a check with words or numbers crossed out.

Instead, if you make a mistake writing a check you can void the check by writing “VOID” in big letters across the check, and write a new one.

Comment: I would also shred the existing check and set it on fire, just to be safe

Comment: @USER_8675309 Would you also salt it and run it through with a wooden stake?

Comment: @Acccumulation I would! Cheques are an undead abomination from the old country.

Comment: @DarcyThomas: Nah. It's ACH that's the abomination. Stamp out ACH and I can secure checks to a reasonable level of security fast.

Comment: @Joshua Ah Yes! The ACH is also an undead abomination from the old country.

Comment: Can't believe people are still using cheques in 2018! Here in Switzerland they were phased out years ago. If you happen to have a cheque from some foreign land, there is only one bank *in the entire country* that can handle it - and the processing fee is $150!

Comment: @OscarBravo is there any bank that would exchange camels? There are some country where they are still used... just curious...

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo Yes but the processing fee is 7.5 camels!